# How to set a parameter value from a SQL Server CTE?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

Given the following SQL:

```
;WITH Results AS
    (
        SELECT ItemListID, Title,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemListID DESC) as intRow, 
        COUNT(ItemListID) OVER() AS ActualNumberOfResults 
        FROM ItemData
        WHERE FREETEXT(Title, @FTSSearchTerm)
        AND WebsiteID = @WebsiteID
        AND ContentTypeID = @ContentTypeID
        AND GeoID2 = @GeoID                                 
     )
SELECT * FROM Results
WHERE intRow BETWEEN @intStartRow AND @intEndRow
ORDER BY ItemListID DESC    

SELECT @NumberOfResultsReturned = @@ROWCOUNT
```

I would like to set a parameter, @ActualNumberOfResults to the value of TOP(1) ActualNumberOfResults that is returned from the CTE.

I used the following, after the CTE, but seems repetitive:

```
SELECT @ActualNumberOfResults = COUNT(*)
FROM ItemData
WHERE CONTAINS(Title, @FTSSearchTerm  )
AND WebsiteID=@WebsiteID
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT ItemListID, Title,
         CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemListID DESC) 
                   BETWEEN @intStartRow AND @intEndRow THEN 1
                   END AS NumberOfResultsReturned,      
         COUNT(ItemListID) OVER() AS ActualNumberOfResults          
  FROM ItemData
  WHERE FREETEXT(Title, @FTSSearchTerm)
        AND WebsiteID = @WebsiteID
        AND ContentTypeID = @ContentTypeID
        AND GeoID2 = @GeoID                                 
 )
 SELECT @NumberOfResultsReturned = COUNT(NumberOfResultsReturned), 
        @ActualNumberOfResults = MAX(ActualNumberOfResults)
 FROM cte
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca3a5/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Visit check this link on the MSDN>  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/c774bb71-84c9-44ce-bfce-a256ecbf56ab

```
;WITH CTE1
 AS (...)
SELECT * FROM CTE1

;WITH CTE2
AS (...)
SELECT * FROM CTE2
```

here your code

```
;WITH Results AS
    (
        SELECT ItemListID, Title,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemListID DESC) as intRow, 
        COUNT(ItemListID) OVER() AS ActualNumberOfResults 
        FROM ItemData
        WHERE FREETEXT(Title, @FTSSearchTerm)
        AND WebsiteID = @WebsiteID
        AND ContentTypeID = @ContentTypeID
        AND GeoID2 = @GeoID                                 
     )
SELECT * FROM Results
WHERE intRow BETWEEN @intStartRow AND @intEndRow
ORDER BY ItemListID DESC   

SELECT @NumberOfResultsReturned = @@ROWCOUNT

;WITH Results1 AS
    (
        SELECT ItemListID, Title,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemListID DESC) as intRow, 
        COUNT(ItemListID) OVER() AS ActualNumberOfResults 
        FROM ItemData
        WHERE FREETEXT(Title, @FTSSearchTerm)
        AND WebsiteID = @WebsiteID
        AND ContentTypeID = @ContentTypeID
        AND GeoID2 = @GeoID                                 
     )

SELECT @ActualNumberOfResults = COUNT(*)
FROM Results1
```